# How can i delay the ajax request so that my ajax loader stays for longer time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the ajaxloader show and hide in my ajaxsetup like this

```
beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
$('.loader').show();
```

---

```
 complete:function(){
         $('.loader').hide();
```

Now the request happens very fast and my animation only loads for merely less than second.

Is there any way i can put some delay so that animation stays there for 3 seconds and then div gets updated.

So basically its delay the ajax call not just delaying the animation because i also dont wnat that ajax request gets completed and animation is still there

Comment: You could time how long the AJAX request takes, then if it hasn't yet been three seconds, set a timeout to wait the remaining time before removing the spinner.

Comment: Have you tried $('.loader').show('slow');

Comment: This is what i want to know how to do that

Comment: @Ray i think slowing the animation has nothing to do with delaying the request. it can show slow or fast but request gets completed in its own time

Comment: What about using an if statement to check when the request is complete, then hiding the loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it has never been crystal clear to me what exactly you're trying to do, here is a solution that does the following:

1. You can only change the jQuery ajax infrastructure - you cannot change all the callers of ajax so you're looking to do things from within the ajax function without changing the calling code.
2. When an ajax call is started, put up progress immediately, but delay the sending of the ajax request for 1.5 seconds.
3. When the ajax call is complete, hide the progress status.

Here's the code:

```
// save old function
$.ajaxOld = $.ajax;

// install our global status hide handler
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function() {
        $('.loader').hide();
    }
});

// replace ajax call with our own that adds the delay
$.ajax = function() {
    // save state from the original function call for use later
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var self = this;

    // show progress immediately
    $('.loader').show();

    // call the original ajax function in 1.5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajaxOld.apply(self, args);
    }, 1500)
}
```

Caveat - this will work as long as no call to `$.ajax()` was expecting it to return the jqXHR object and there is no use of ajax deferreds.  If those are used, then a more complicated solution would need to be coded that holds off the success handler and completion handler.

---

Edit: these are older attempts to understand what the question was:

To make sure the notification is on screen for a minimum amount of time, you could do this:

```
beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
    xhr.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    $('.loader').show();

complete:function(xhr){
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - xhr.startTime;
    if (elapsed < 3000) {
        $('.loader').delay(3000 - elapsed).hide(1);
    } else {
        $('.loader').hide();
    }
```

This will keep track of how long the message was on screen and if the ajax call went quickly, it will delay hiding the msg until 3 seconds have elapsed.  If the ajax call didn't go quickly and the message has already been displayed long enough, it will just hide it when the ajax call completes.

---

If what you want to do is to delay the loading of the content and you are processing the result in the `complete` handler, then you can do that like this:

```
function finishMyAjax(xhr) {
    // load your ajax content
    $('.loader').hide();
}

    beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
        xhr.startTime = new Date().getTime();
        $('.loader').show();

    complete:function(xhr){
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - xhr.startTime;
        var self = this;
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        if (elapsed < 3000) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                finishMyAjax.apply(self, args);
            }, 3000-elapsed);
        } else {
            finishMyAjax.apply(this, arguments);
        }
```

If you are not processing the result of the ajax all in the complete handler, then please include the code for processing the result so I can include it in this idea.  The general idea here is that you record the time when the ajax call starts.  If when the ajax response comes, it has been less than 3 seconds, you set a timer for the amount of remaining time in the 3 seconds and finish the response in the timer callback.  If it's been more than 3 seconds, then you just go ahead and process the result normally.

This allows you to never use more time than desired, but always at least 3 seconds.  You could just delay launching the ajax call for 3 seconds, but then if you ajax call takes 6 seconds to get a result, the whole process would take 9 seconds which is not what you want.  In my scheme, if the ajax result takes 1 second, you will delay processing it until 3 seconds.  If the ajax result takes 6 seconds, the result will get processed right when it comes in (no extra 3 second delay).

Comment: I tried ur script. First my animation stayed there forever. Seconds you are just delaying the animation not request . My Div box gets updated in Success handler already and animation still stays there. The other i can do is to timeout the updating of div. But is there any way to delay the request via javascript

Comment: @user1730491 - it was not clear exactly what you were asking.  If you really want to delay the processing of the response, then I've added an option for that if you are processing the response in the `complete:` handler.  If you are not, then you need to include the code where you process the response.

Comment: i don't know but that delay function is not working . i have logged the message in console and i am in the loop and i tried delay(12000) and even then it got hidden quickly

Comment: @user1730491 - yes you are correct.  I just corrected my answer.  You need to pass a parameter to `.hide(1)` to make it into an animation so it works with the `.delay(xx)`.

Comment: now your code is working with animation but if i put the div update code in your function , then it means i have to hard code every function for that. I was just looking for something that i can put in ajaxSetup so that it work across whole ajax calls and requests. i mean just some code in `beforeSend` so that response gets delayed by 3 seconds and i don't need to touch the other code

Comment: @user1730491 - Are you trying to delay the actual processing of the ajax results?  Or just make sure the processing message is up for at least 3 seconds?  Your question is still not clear on this point.

Comment: Well i only want that what ever i do should be done in ajaxSetup only with minimal coding. IF we delay the processing message then i think i have to hard code in many functions. But if you have something which delay the actual request so that i don't need to chnaging other functions , that will be good

Comment: @user1730491 - can you please answer my previous question.  Are you trying to delay the actual processing of the ajax results or just the hiding of the progress message?  I need to know that in order to answer further.

Comment: Preferably i want to delay the actual request

Comment: @user1730491 - Do you want to always add 3 seconds to the total time that the ajax call takes (like delay sending the ajax call for 3 seconds) or do you want to only make it be at least 3 seconds, but not longer than 3 seconds if it doens't need to be?

Comment: I appreciate your effort.Just make it always 1.5 seconds. that will be ok and code will also be less

Comment: @user1730491 - OK I added one more attempt at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy , that was great , i will implement you solution and i don't want to waste your time as well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could either delay the hiding of the loader in the client or sleep the server.

In JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.loader').hide() }, 3000)
```

Or in PHP before echoing out the result:

```
sleep(3)
```

Assuming PHP but other languages have the same functionality maybe named differently.
Keep in mind that the 3 seconds of sleep will be in addition to the time the response takes.

**Edit:** If you want to delay to whole request try this:

```
function request(delay) {
  // beforeSend logic here
  $('.loader').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
      ...
      complete: function() { $('.loader').hide(); }
      ...
    });
  }, delay);
}
```

Then just call `request(delay)` whenever you need it.

Comment: I tried settimeout , although it loads the animation longer but ajax request gets completed and div gets updated and spinner is still spinning

Comment: Is there anyhthing i can put in ajaxsetup which delays every request to ajax. Because i am not harcoding the $.ajax. i am just setting up the ajaxSetup so that it works across whole site. Is there anything i can put only in ajaxSetup

Comment: in C# you can delay the function return by putting the below line just before return - System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);  Here 8000 is the millisecods.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to show ajax loader while processing ajax request

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display="inline";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display="none";
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","yourRequestController",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div  id="loader" style="display:none">
    you are seeing this MSG becoz our ajax loader is processing ,
    it will automatically hide when your ajax request is completed
 // place your ajax loader imagae rather than showing a msg
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">Content Before</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Its w3schools.com ajax example , I just modified code to show ajax loader